# Fallback background property for @media css function

Tags: html, css

I am using these css commands:

```
@media all and (max-width:1050px) {
body {
    background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat left top;
    background-position:-481px 0;
}
}
@media not all and (max-width:1050px) {
body {
background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center top;
}
}
body {
line-height:1;
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: 'roboto_condensedregular';
}
```

This allows me to have 2 different background settings for different screen widths, however....

In older browsers the background is blank, I am guessing its because older browsers cannot look inside the media tag.

My question is, how do i do a fallback for older browsers so if whatever browser doesnt support media tag it still falls back on some other css to show a background?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the fallback `background`styles *first*, then override them for each screen size